# Visualforce Remoting Exception: Error parsing json response: 'Unexpected token <'. Logged in?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, javascript-remoting

I am trying to use VF remoting in a public site and get the error 'Visualforce Remoting Exception: Error parsing json response: 'Unexpected token <'.  Logged in?' when viewing page from a public site guest user context.  The remoting is being used by a jquery autocomplete component.

If I test the page from a non-url redirected, sys admin perspective it works as expected.

The site does use URL rewrites, and the site guest user profile has access to all information being searched in the database.  It seems to be an authentication issue?  If anyone has seen anything like this and has any suggestions re resolution they'd be most appreciated. Im stuck!

Cheers,
CH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok - looks like someone else sorted this and I just stumbled onto their great response.

The issue lies in the url rewriter class, and the mapping from an external 'pretty' url to an internal url with '/apex/' in it makes SF decide it needs to be logged in whilst accessing the remoting logic.

Thus, when the VF remoting request is made we need to ignore it and let it pass unchanged. Per the great solution writeup at following link,you check the inbound url for contains 'apexremote' as indicator of whether to exclude from mapping logic.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000099DOIAY for more details.

Comment: I know it's too early right now, but remember you can mark this as the accepted answer in a day or two!

Comment: So this definitely fixes the issue, by returning the PageReference of '../Your_VF_Page'. However, I had an org where only '/Your_VF_Page' was allowed and didn't cause any errors. Could this be related to some DNS issues on how the SITE is configured? Because to me, adding the '..' in front of the page seems like a workaround instead of a fix (although it does work!)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Visualforce Remoting problem was to do with URL rewriting, but it's worth knowing you can create a [public REST web service](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html) to do the same thing.

Comment: interesting thanks @metadaddy! I will try the url rewriting fix first and then if it fails looks like Im going to be writing REST... :)

Comment: Interested to know if it works!

Comment: @metadaddy - I'm using Visualforce remoting in a public Force.com site (as per the OP) to both retrieve and update records without problems.  Are you referring to web sites external to Salesforce perchance?

Comment: Geez got the heavyweights across this one! :D I can confirm that by bypassing the rewriter logic IF inbound url contains 'apexremote' works and all is good in the universe once more...

Comment: @metadaddy works for me :P https://fflib-ext-common-developer-edition.na11.force.com/

Comment: Well, I learn something new every day - that'll teach me to make unfounded assumptions! Edited my answer!