# Error parsing json response: 'expected expression, got '<''. Logged in?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, remote-action

I'm calling a remote action which returns a wrapper. It works without any issues on most of the time. But sometimes, it throwing an error:

> Error parsing json response: 'expected expression, got '<''. Logged
>   in?.

This is usually happens if there's remote action call after the page is idle for sometime approx. 20 minutes.

I found a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24143/visualforce-remoting-exception-error-parsing-json-response-unexpected-token). In my page I'm not using URLReWriter as mentioned. So it does not helping me to solve my issue.

Am I missing something? or Do I have to do it in another way?

Here's my code:

```
@RemoteAction
    public static SearchResult getAllInstructors(Boolean isConflictSearch, ConflictSearchParameter conflictSearch, SearchParameter parameters) {
    SearchResult contactList = new SearchResult();
    contactList = getAllInstructorsWithoutConflictCheck(parameters);
    if(isConflictSearch) {
        //Search Instructors without conflicts
        contactList.conflictCount = getInstructorsWithConflictsCheck(conflictSearch, parameters, getContactIdSet(contactList.instructors));
    }
    return contactList;
}
public class SearchResult {
    public List<Contact> instructors;
    public Map<Id, Integer> conflictCount;
    public Map<Id, Double> proximities;
    public Map<Id, Decimal> instructorScore;
    public Integer recordCount;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code snippet?

Comment: Also could you please check what is your session timeout period?

Comment: Session timeout period is 2 hours.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @jonathanwiesel We created a case regarding this. The response is to disable the **Cross-Site Request Forgery** from the Session Settings. After that we did not see the issue again so far.

Comment: Today I was also getting the same error. Finally found out that the return type of method was too complex. it was MAP of LIST. When I changed it to simple return type, like list of object. It started working.
Hence in my case error is misleading though.

Comment: @MelbinT would you mind posting your solution as an actual answer ? That'd be more obvious to other people running into this issue.